# NodeJS library for running an open, forwarding HTTP proxy (used to hide the IP of requester)

Tags: node.js, proxy

Most of the NodeJS proxy libraries are specialized for reverse proxy purposes but I wasn't able to find any library for running a forwarding HTTP proxy.

Answer (score 0):

One option is `http-proxy`:

```
const http      = require('http');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const proxy     = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: req.url });
}).listen(9000, () => {
  console.log("Waiting for requests...");
});
```

Comment: This is bad because http-proxy is not specialized as a forwarding proxy and therefore doesn't understand the HTTP CONNECT method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel#HTTP_CONNECT_method). Any other ideas? Should be something like Squid.